# How can I navigate to a different URL when user clicks the hyperlink in the GridView with a condition?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I am a beginner in learning asp.net. I have a column in a GridView with header name `FORM ID`. I want to be able to navigate to the different URL based on the part of the `FORM ID`.

For example,

- Clicking on *abc10001* will take us to "~/abc1.aspx?formid=abc10001"
- Clicking on *abc20001* will take us to "~/abc2.aspx?formid=abc20001"

I understand the use of the MID function like so `v=MID(string,4,1)` to capture the 4th value and redirect to page by determining the value `v` but I do not know how to apply this correctly. Please guide me. Your help is greatly appreciated.

The following is the aspx code I'm currently work on :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">           
    <columns>
        <asp:Hyperlinkfield DataTextField="formid" HeaderText="Form ID" ItemStyle-  Width="150px" 
            DataNavigateUrlFields="formid" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/abc1.aspx" />         
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What if you routed everything to the same page, but passed a different query string value? That's far easier. For example: `~/abc.aspx?id=1`

Comment: The module and content will be different for both abc1.aspx and abc2.aspx.

Comment: Then have the page load the necessary data based on the query string value. And if you're going to have static pages like that, it doesn't really make sense to generate links in a grid view loaded from some data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch your `Hyperlinkfield` to a `TemplateField` with a `HyperLink` control to give you more control over the `NavigateUrl` like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Form ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("formid") %>'
            NavigateUrl='<%# "~/abc" + Mid(Eval("formid"), 4, 1) + ".aspx" %>'>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out for this question!

Comment: @NgZen You're welcome. Welcome to StackOverflow. Accepting and voting answers is thanks enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code which is working successfully :

```
<asp:GridView ID="child" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Form ID" >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Hyperlink runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("formid") %>' 
         NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("formid","~/abc" + Mid(Eval("formid"), 4, 1) + ".aspx?formid={0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Credits to @mason and @Tony L. for helping me out on this issue.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize you also needed the query string on the end. Glad you got it working.